# It is possible to provider some default given contextual for class method?

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-3

Suppose I have defined a class `Test`:

```
import scala.collection.{IterableFactory, Factory}

class Test:
    def p1[C[_]](xs: Int*)(using f: Factory[Int, C[Int]]): C[Int] = f.fromSpecific(xs)
    def p2[C[_]](xs: Int*)(using f: IterableFactory[C]): C[Int] = f(xs*)
```

Then I can write following codes since there are implicit methods `implicit def iterableFactory[A]: Factory[A, CC[A]] = IterableFactory.toFactory(this)` defined in `List`, `Seq`, etc.:

```
 val t = new Test
 t.p1[List](1, 2, 3)
```

However, I can not write `t.p2[List](1, 2, 3)` directly. Instead I must define `given IterableFactory[List]` first, or using `t.p2(1, 2, 3)(using List)`.

My question: Is there any solution such that `t.p2(1, 2, 3)` works automatically? Such as define some given instances in `object Test` or so?

Comment: Why do you need `p2`? Why is `p1` not enough?

Comment: As far as I can tell these 2 have different use cases: `Factory` can be used as an implicit or passed into `collection.to(factory)`, `IterableFactory` is supposed to be a common interface for collection's companion object and I never saw it used as an implicit. `IterableFactory` can be _implicitly converted_ to `Factory` but you _pass it explicitly_ to all these places which expect `Factory`.